# ios5 storyboard version of Facebook integration

Tags: ios, facebook, ios5

Just curious if there is an existing storyboard version of Facebook integration around because I've been googling for about 2 days. So far, I can do authorization for my app and what I have in mind is to try posting a simple status message perhaps from my app to my Facebook newsfeed. Most of the demos / tutorials I've gone through use xib's though such as [this](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/03/28/facebook-sdk-posting-to-user-news-feed/). This one is a good tutorial, however I want a storyboard version for this. Tell me if this post is a dupe and kindly post that question so I can study it.

I know there were a lot here that know the idea of sharing :)
So any helpful links were very much appreciated, as it will, in a way, boost my learning experience as well as the others who are starting iOS development :)

Thanks!

Comment: Let me see if I understand, you want some xib that would illustrate like facebook news feed? If so, I don't think that this exists. I will probably have to create one for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it has been quite some months  since someone already gave attention to this :D Anyway, my bad I just noticed that I didn't specified that in this post that I want a simple storyboard version for this Facebook functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a simple example of an iOS app using Storyboards (iOS5 and later): https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-social-cafe

Hopefully that's helpful and shows how to do a good authorization flow with Storyboarding.

Good luck.

Comment: I've tried installing the social cafe by following the directions specified. However, the AdSupport and Social Frameworks were missing. How could I go about it?

Comment: Oh my, it seems I need to upgrade my Xcode for this. This seems to be a good project though.

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to simply post a status update you should be able to use the same examples that are shown in nib files. However if you want to see a sample app that uses story boards you can take a look at this sample app:

https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-social-cafe

It uses story boards to set up the UI and perform facebook login. You can also check it out to see how to use the new UI pickers (friends, place) and how to do open graph actions.

If you have more specific details around how you want to post a status update, please provide them so I can clarify further.